# FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException ERROR_CUSTOM_TOKEN_MISMATCH

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have problems with Firebase Phone Auth. 
Previously I used debug version and firebase account of user A. Then, we made publication on play market and it stopped sending sms. 
I remove this project to another firebase acc that belongs to play services account owner. Created app, correctly fill in app id, connected it with play market app and then got json file from firebase and placed it in project.
When call to sendSms, nothing happpens (I did not change realization, only moved project from one acc to another)
Logs says

> 07-22 15:30:35.965 32553-32553/ru.falcode.lcd_android
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>   com.google.firebase.auth not found. 
>   07-22 15:30:35.966
>   32553-32553/ru.falcode.lcd_android W/BiChannelGoogleApi:
>   [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@3e65d46 07-22 15:30:35.977
>   32553-32761/ru.falcode.lcd_android W/DynamiteModule: Local module
>   descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found. 07-22
>   15:30:35.984 32553-32761/ru.falcode.lcd_android I/FirebaseAuth:
>   [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
>       [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation 07-22 15:30:36.240 32553-32615/ru.falcode.lcd_android
>   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service 07-22 15:30:36.608
>   32553-32553/ru.falcode.lcd_android W/TAG: onVerificationFailed
>       com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token corresponds to a different audience. [ App ID does
>   not match requested project. ]
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzce.zzb(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdf.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdg.run(Unknown Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 07-22
>   15:30:36.608 32553-32553/ru.falcode.lcd_android
>
> E/FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token
>   corresponds to a different audience. [ App ID does not match requested
>   project. ]
>       ERROR_CUSTOM_TOKEN_MISMATCH

We never used custom keys. Just an example from git hub with no customization over it.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree the error code is confusing. But the error message is key here: "App ID does not match requested project. " The same app used to obtain the phone auth credential should be the one used to sign in with it. That is why you are getting the error. It seems like you are getting the phone auth credential with one application and then signing in with that credential using another app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are testing your project with a normal `.apk` in your mobile or in the emulator. If you want to test your project for mobile authentication you have to provide your mobile number in the **firebase** mobile authentication in sing-in-method. Testing the mobile number(Optional mobile number) by which you want to test. Or you make a signed `.apk` and then try it again I think it will work fine.